# How to enable ExecutorServiceMetrics in SpringBoot 2.1.2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

How to enable ExecutorServiceMetrics listed here ?

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/ExecutorServiceMetrics.java

SpringBoot version: 2.1.2.RELEASE

Under /actuator/metrics I can see jvm and some other outofbox auto configured metrics, but not executor metrics.

I have tried setting this, but no luck.

```java
management:
  metrics:
    enable.executor: true
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get `ExecutorServiceMetrics` reporting metrics in a Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE app and didn't have to do any more than create a monitored `ExecutorService` bean. I didn't have to add anything to my `application.yml` or `application.properties` to make this work.

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig {

    @Bean
    public ExecutorService executorService(final MeterRegistry registry) {
        return ExecutorServiceMetrics.monitor(registry, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20), "my executor", Tags.of("key", "value"));
    }
}
```

Then, just wire your `executorService` bean into your components and submit tasks to that `executorService` bean.

Comment: What if there are more than 1 thread pools

Comment: should add `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 4):

I found that you had to do it manually if you want to lock it in with Spring Boot. I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.9.RELEASE.

Create a ExecutorServiceMetrics bean, using the "applicationTaskExecutor" bean (that way, you get whatever bean size has previously been configured). It will automatically get bound.

Something like:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ExecutorServiceMetrics executorServiceMetrics(@Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor") ThreadPoolTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor) {
    return new ExecutorServiceMetrics(applicationTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor(), "applicationTaskExecutor",
            Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it (in kotlin):

```kotlin
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
class AsyncConfig(
        private val taskExecutorBuilder: TaskExecutorBuilder,
        private val meterRegistry: MeterRegistry) : AsyncConfigurer {

    /**
     * Add monitoring of executor using micrometer.
     */
    override fun getAsyncExecutor(): Executor {
        // create executor based on default spring-boot properties
        val executor = taskExecutorBuilder.build()
        // we need to initialize it before calling monitor
        executor.initialize()
        // monitor the executor (so it is available in metrics) (must be wrapped)
        return ExecutorServiceMetrics.monitor(meterRegistry, executor.threadPoolExecutor, "AsyncExecutor", "async")
    }

}
```

So basically:

- make use of the autowired `TaskExecutorBuilder` so the executor is built depending on the `spring.task.execution.*` properties
- wrap the thread pool executor in `ExecutorServiceMetrics` (from `io.micrometer.core`) to get the metrics

Note that for this to work, you must return the decorated executor !

In this example and since I gave a prefix (`async`), the metrics available are:

- *async.executor*
- *async.executor.active*
- *async.executor.completed*
- *async.executor.idle*
- *async.executor.pool.core*
- *async.executor.pool.max*
- *async.executor.pool.size*
- *async.executor.queue.remaining*
- *async.executor.queued*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether a `meterRegistry` bean exists, you could try to use `ObjectMapper`

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig {
    @Bean
    public ExecutorService executorService(ObjectProvider<MeterRegistry> meterRegistryProvider) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        meterRegistryProvider.ifAvailable(registry -> ExecutorServiceMetrics.monitor(registry, executorService, "my executor", Tags.of("key", "value")));
        return executorService;
    }
}
```